# Generalized number to string conversion in Java

Tags: java, string, numbers

I'm working on a program in Java and I have run into a small problem. I'm accepting user input that includes a number, but I have no way of knowing how that number is represented (i.e.: it could be "42", "42.0", "42.00001", etc.). If I use, say, `Float.parseFloat`, it won't accept integer strings ("42"), while if I use `Integer.parseInteger`, it won't accept float strings ("42.0"). Is there any kind of generalized string-to-number conversion function in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you're not getting any extraneous characters in your input to parseFloat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Float.parseFloat

```
groovy> Float.parseFloat("4")
4.0
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Float.parseFloat sure does parse numbers without a decimal or exponent component.

Comment: Odd, I was using `Float.parseFloat` before and it wasn't working. Let me look into it before I mark you as correct.

Comment: And curse your speedy groovy shenaniganery, sir.

Comment: Doh! I was using `Scanner.next()` rather than `Scanner.nextLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Q9146065 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "32";
        float a = Float.parseFloat(test);
        float b = 10;
        System.out.println(a + b);
    }
}
```

Sure enough prints out 42.0 for me so it is parsing 32 fine...